# Instalar Qt en Visual Studio

Tags: qt, vs

He tratado repetidas veces de instalar `Qt creator` y se me ha hecho imposible, sencillamente el `Qt creator` no funciona en mi maquina. Por otro lado, teniendo en cuenta la situación, trate de descargar el plugin que tiene `VS 2019` guiándome por este video de youtube `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bXrfVrYyxk&t=345s&ab_channel=CreativePotatoProgramming` y a la hora de agregar la ruta que exige `VS` para usar el plugin, me da el siguiente error

```
--- qmake: Querying persistent properties
--- qmake(16240): exit code 0 (113,1 msecs)

Exception "El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado":
   en System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   en System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   en System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   en QtVsTools.Core.HelperFunctions.SetVCVars(VersionInformation VersionInfo, ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   en QtVsTools.Core.QMake.Run(Boolean setVCVars)
Error reading VS project settings

Stacktrace:
   en QtVsTools.Core.VersionInformation..ctor(String qtDirIn)
   en QtVsTools.Core.VersionInformation.Get(String qtDir)
   en QtVsTools.Options.QtVersionsPage.SaveSettingsToStorage()
```

P.D: ya tengo descargado el Qt 6.1.0 y es de la carpeta de instalación de msvc2019 de la cual estoy sacando la ruta que pide, en otras palabras, no me la estoy inventando.

Comment: Y cual seria la pregunta?

Comment: Es muy difícil entender?. Como puedo instalar Qt en Visual Studio.

Comment: Y la verdad que si... porque hay un plugin para visual studio que salta en la primera  busqueda que haces en google... y eso te dio algun problema?

Comment: @gbianchi Si, el problema esta en que para poder usar el plugin te exige poner la ruta de un compilador especifico (mscv, que por lo que entiendo no es realmente un compilador) y no logro descargar ninguna versión de qt que utilice ese 'compilador'